# RestKit serialize objects shortcut

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, restkit

is there a shorter way to do this?

iam fetching all core data objects with some predicate and then parsing them to JSON, using RestKit and defined mapping... i still want to use RestKit, but cant it be done more simple?

```
- (NSArray *)serializedManagedObjectClass:(Class)managedObjectClass updatedSinceRevision:(long long)revision {

    NSArray * managedObjects = [managedObjectClass MR_findAllSortedBy:@"createdDate" ascending:YES withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"revision > %lld", revision]];

    NSError * error = nil;

    NSMutableArray * serializedObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[managedObjects count]];

    for (NSManagedObject * managedObject in managedObjects) {

        id object = [NSMutableDictionary new];

        RKObjectMappingOperation * op = [RKObjectMappingOperation mappingOperationFromObject:managedObject toObject:object withMapping:[self.objectManager.mappingProvider serializationMappingForClass:managedObjectClass]];
        BOOL success = [op performMapping:&error];

        if ((success) && (error == nil) && (object)) {
            [serializedObjects addObject:object];
        } else {
            ALog(@"Serialization problem with %@, possible error %@", managedObject, error);
        }

    }

    return serializedObjects;
}
```

Comment: Are these serialized objects being sent to a server with RestKit?

Comment: yes, along with other parameters

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to map each object individually. As long as you have set the serialization mapping for that class, RestKit will handle the serialization when you try to send instances of that object. It looks like you have already created and assigned the mapping for the class.

Now, just add your array of managed objects to your dictionary of parameters that are being sent to the server. RestKit should then map each object according to the mapping provided.